# Insert Into Multiple values table using stored procedure and DataAccessLayer

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I am trying making a test on how to add multiple values into a column, which accepts multiple values.

For example, I have two tables

```
Table 1: contains `ID` (`int`) primary, `Name` (`varchar`)
Table 2: contains `ID` (reference to Table 1's `ID`), `Image` (`image`)
```

I created these tables, and I can insert data into table one, but how can I let it insert into multiple value column in table 2 (`Image`)?

I can have Id and add images how much I want, I tried with stored procedure, using insert, but failed, because I want to check ID is the same to ID in table 1 using where statement not working in insert

For more examples.

```
ID: 1, Name: Willam, Image:[AnyImage] (More than 1 image)
ID: 2, Name: Edi, Image[Anyknownimage], Image[AnyNewImage] etc...
```

Anything that helps?

Comment: Tag properly!!!  MySQL <> SQL Server.  Which one is this????

Comment: Not Identity, it's about insert multiple values in same table

Comment: Why do you have Image in both tables?  Image should not be in the 1st table.

Comment: Alright, I changed it.

Comment: The `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a solution to my Question.
The way I should do is to Set Identity_insert to on before insert and turn it off after insert in a procedure.
Before the Set insert.

```
    CREATE proc [dbo].[Add_Image]
@ID int,
@Image image
as
Insert into ImageContainer(ID,Image) values(@ID,@Image)
```

After the altering the table to:

```
 CREATE proc [dbo].[Add_Image]
@ID int,
@Image image
as
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ImageContainer ON
Insert into ImageContainer(ID,Image) values(@ID,@Image)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ImageContainer off
```

Thanks to you all